Invalid Signature when I try to join zoom meeting
I want to join zoom meeting from my reactjs app using zoom sdk.
I have downloaded zoom sdk code from internet and it is working using nodejs and reactjs.
But In my app I have reactjs as frontend and nestjs with graphql and typescript.
I made graphql api to generate signature but not working.
I have added code.
Please review it and help me to resolve it.
Thank you in advance!
below is the api which generates signature :
async getSignature(
    GetSignatureInput: GetSignatureInput,
    user: JwtPayload
  ): Promise<any> {
    const sdkKey = process.env.ZOOM_CLIENT_ID;
    const clientID = process.env.ZOOM_CLIENT_ID;
    const clientSecret = process.env.ZOOM_CLIENT_SECRET;
    const role = 0;
    const expirationSeconds = 7200;

    const zoomTokenApiUrl = process.env.ZOOM_TOKEN_API_URL;
    const zoomAccountId = process.env.ZOOM_ACCOUNT_ID;
    const zoomApiCredentials = `${process.env.ZOOM_CLIENT_ID}:${process.env.ZOOM_CLIENT_SECRET}`;
    const auth = `Basic ${Buffer.from(zoomApiCredentials).toString('base64')}`;

    const roles = [0, 1]
    try {
      const { lesson_id } = GetSignatureInput;

      if (!lesson_id || lesson_id == "") {
        throw new Error('must provide valid lession id!');
      }

      if (!roles.includes(role)) {
        throw new Error('role must be 0 or 1!');
      }

      if (!(expirationSeconds >= 1800 && expirationSeconds <= 172800)) {
        throw new Error("Expiration seconds must be between 1800 and 172800");
      }

      const lessionDetails = await this.courseLessionRepository.findOneBy({ id: lesson_id });

      if (!lessionDetails) {
        throw new Error(`lesson not found with id = ${lesson_id} !`);
      }
      const meeting_url = lessionDetails.meeting_url;

      const url = new URL(meeting_url);
      const meetingNumber = url.pathname.split('/')[2];
      const password = url.searchParams.get('pwd');

      const iat = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
      const exp = expirationSeconds ? iat + expirationSeconds : iat + 60 * 60 * 4
      const oHeader = { alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' }

      const oPayload = {
        appKey: clientID,
        sdkKey: clientID,
        mn: meetingNumber,
        role,
        iat,
        exp,
        tokenExp: exp
      }

      const sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader)
      const sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload)
      const sdkJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign('HS256', sHeader, sPayload, clientSecret);

      // get zoom access token
      const response = await axios.post(zoomTokenApiUrl, `grant_type=account_credentials&account_id=${zoomAccountId}`, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Authorization': auth
        }
      });
      const accessToken = response.data.access_token;

      console.log('accessToken -->>', accessToken);

      const respObj =  {
        username : `${user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}`,
        email : user.email,
        sdkJWT: sdkJWT,
        sdkKey: sdkKey,
        meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
        password: password
      }

      return respObj
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw new Error(error);
    }

  }

below is the frontend  code :
const ZoomMeeting = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const token = queryParams.get('token');
    var authEndpoint = 'http://localhost:4000/getSignature'
    var sdkKey = 'lpV0crDbQbmrL69bcIPsg'
    var meetingNumber = '81084959855'
    var passWord = 'f91GPE4peZb2RHzqp9gX7mLWfDrVsU'
    var role = 0
    var userName = 'Trupal'
    var userEmail = 'trupal.vasava@jainam.in'
    var registrantToken = ''
    var zakToken = token;
    var leaveUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'
  
    function getSignature(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      startMeeting("signature-token")
    }
  
    function startMeeting(signature) {
      document.getElementById('zmmtg-root').style.display = 'block'
      console.log('registrantToken -->>', registrantToken);

      const mySignature = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBLZXkiOiJscFYwY3JEYlFibXJMNjliY0lQc2ciLCJzZGtLZXkiOiJscFYwY3JEYlFibXJMNjliY0lQc2ciLCJtbiI6Ijg1OTAwMTY0NTE3Iiwicm9sZSI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNzI0NDc5OTYxLCJleHAiOjE3MjQ0ODcxNjEsInRva2VuRXhwIjoxNzI0NDg3MTYxfQ.Keq3sMudZhq0B8OQdUY4oxek5VV1yKYKi7rUrKh-ExY"
  
      ZoomMtg.init({
        leaveUrl: leaveUrl,
        patchJsMedia: true,
        meetingInfo: [],
        leaveOnPageUnload: true,
        success: () => {            
          ZoomMtg.join({
            signature: mySignature,
            sdkKey,
            meetingNumber,
            passWord,
            userName,
            userEmail,
            tk: registrantToken,
            zak: sign,
            success: (success) => {
              console.log(success)
              ZoomMtg.getAttendeeslist({});
              ZoomMtg.getCurrentUser({
            success: function (res) {
              console.log("success getCurrentUser", res.result.currentUser);
            },
          });
            },
            error: (error) => {
              console.log(error)
            }
          })
  
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      })
    }
  
    return (
      <div className="test" style={{width: 300, height:300}}>
        <main>
          <h1>Zoom Meeting SDK Sample React</h1>
  
          <button onClick={getSignature}>Join Meeting</button>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }

Nodejs code Which is working :
  app.post('/getSignature', (req, res) => {
    const requestBody = coerceRequestBody(req.body)
    const validationErrors = validateRequest(requestBody, propValidations, schemaValidations)
    if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: validationErrors })
    }
    const { meetingNumber, role, expirationSeconds } = requestBody
    const iat = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    const exp = expirationSeconds ? iat + expirationSeconds : iat + 60 * 60 * 4
    const oHeader = { alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' }
    const oPayload = {
      appKey: clientID,
      sdkKey: clientID,
      mn: meetingNumber,
      role,
      iat,
      exp,
      tokenExp: exp
    }
    const sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader)
    const sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload)
    const sdkJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign('HS256', sHeader, sPayload, clientSecret)
    return res.json({ signature: sdkJWT })
  })

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const authorizationUrl = `https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientID}&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}`;
    res.json({
        success: true,
        redirectUrl: authorizationUrl,
    });
});

app.get('/oauth/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const authorizationCode = req.query.code;
    try {
        const tokenResponse = await axios.post('https://zoom.us/oauth/token', querystring.stringify({
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code: authorizationCode,
            redirect_uri: redirectURI
        }), {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${clientID}:${clientSecret}`).toString('base64')}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
        const accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
        res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/ZoomMeeting?token=${accessToken}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error exchanging authorization code for access token:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error during authentication.');
    }
});

I want to convert nodejs code to my nestjs API using graphql.
Please help me to resolve it.
